# Money-rails gem rails and js dynamic select of dropdown

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, money-rails

I have seed Country with name, number_code and iso. For Currency I have used money-rails gem. When I select Country I want user to autoselect its correspoinding currency. When I select USA auto selct USD and if user wants to chnage currency they can change it as well.

I have done this with ajax.

I have method in controller get_currency I got response `{"currency":{"name":"Aruban Florin","symbol":"ƒ","iso_code":"AWG"}}`.

```
    // country, currency select dropdown start
    var countryDropdown = $('#country-select');
    var currencyDropdown = $('#currency-select');
    
    // Handle country dropdown change and set initial state of currency dropdown
    function updateCurrencyDropdown(countryId) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/company_countries/get_currency',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { country_id: countryId },
        success: function(response) {
          var currency = response.currency;
          var currencyOption;
          var selectedCurrency = currencyDropdown.val();

          if (currency && currency.name) {
            console.log(currency)
            currencyOption = `<option value="${currency.iso_code}">${currency.name} (${currency.symbol})</option>`;
            console.log(currencyOption)
            currencyDropdown.find(`option[value="${currency.iso_code}"]`).remove(); // remove currency option from the dropdown
            currencyDropdown.prepend(currencyOption); // Add new currency option at the top
            if (selectedCurrency !== currency.iso_code) {
              currencyDropdown.val(currency.iso_code);
              console.log("currencyDropdown", currencyDropdown)
            }
          } else {
            currencyOption = '<option value="USD">US Dollar (USD)</option>';
            currencyDropdown.empty().append(currencyOption); // Clear previous options and add default option
          }
        }
      });
    }

    // Set initial state of currency dropdown based on initial value of country dropdown
    var initialCountryId = countryDropdown.val();
    updateCurrencyDropdown(initialCountryId);

    // Handle country dropdown change
    countryDropdown.on('change', function() {
      var countryId = $(this).val();
      updateCurrencyDropdown(countryId);
    });
    // country, currency select dropdown end
```

I got only 1 or 2 optins here. If I select Austria get Euro and USD. What about list of other currency as an option.